# Loadbalancing and Ado.net DataRow

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, ado.net, load-balancing

I am working on a .net brownfield project currently built in legacy .net 2.0 which uses traditional Ado.net. We are working on the sprint revamp of the project trying to make it service based which we are planning to deploy on a load balancer. Question is does DataRow work in a load balanced scenario and if so how? Can I use datarow inside the method and the return a datatable so that it can be serialized or can i not use datarow at all. As per my knowledge I am aware that in a load balanced cluster every object has to inherit ISerializable.So please suggest??

Comment: _"...return a datatable..."_ - to where? clients?

Comment: It's probably better to load data from your database into objects and store that into a distributed memory cache like Redis or Memcached that can be accessed via your cluster instead of trying to share DB resources

Comment: The key to load balancing is idempotency.  If your services are idempotent they'll scale behind a load balancer.  There's no reason why you couldn't use a DataRow with a load balancer provided you enforce idempotency in your service.